# Is there any information on running Nutch 2.0 in deploy mode?

Tags: apache, hadoop, nutch

The only information I can find from google searching is how to run Nutch 1.3 in deploy mode. This does not suit me as I'm using Nutch 2.0. Are there any articles/tutorials? I even have a book and it too uses Nutch 1.0. I simply cannot find anything to do with Nutch 2.0 in deploy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Although the process is explained for Nutch 1.x and Nutch 2.x is different in many aspects to master/1.x.

The Hadoop deployment is not different. As soon as you have the `.job` file and the proper/final configuration you can deploy the job into your Hadoop cluster like you would do with any other job. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried following the only Nutch 1.0 Hadoop tutorial here: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial but had trouble getting jobs to run using the hadoop command. Maybe I was just doing it wrong. I can try again.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9zjcTjjjyU it's a nice tutorial, focused on Amazon EMR, but can help you. Do you already have a working hadoop cluster?

Comment: This Julien guy is everywhere! OK, I'll take a look - thanks!

Comment: This video didn't help me at all. Hadoop is already configured and it shows a Nutch 1.0 crawl.

Comment: The I'm afraid that what you need is how to set up your own Hadoop cluster. The basic steps in the Nutch 1.x ~should~ apply, although it may vary depending on the Hadoop version. In general, Nutch will run as one additional job in your Hadoop cluster there is nothing special needed only for Nutch.

Comment: I was able to get Hadoop running but of course I got stuck on the inject job because I didn't have zookeeper installed and running which I'm afraid to do because it messes with HBase's personally managed zookeeper instance. Do I really even need Hadoop? Can I just run in local mode?

Comment: You can run it in local mode. Normally you would run it in Hadoop when 1 single node/machine is not enough to run the entire crawl in an acceptable time.

Comment: Good. Thank you for your help.